# selection with charindex issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to separate this string into different columns using the 'a ' as separator

```
005031812180200000100aRemaining Inside Terminala Cassette 1(BIN1)/c:HTG 21,000a Cassette 2(BIN2)/c:HTG 23,000a Cassette 3(BIN3)/d:HTG 47,000a Cassette 4(BIN4)/d:HTG 48,000a Total : HTG 139,000aaaad
```

I'm creating an object with this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([cassette_1] [nvarchar] (500),
                [cassette_2] [nvarchar] (500),
                [cassette_3] [nvarchar] (500),
                [cassette_4] [nvarchar] (500),
                [total] [nvarchar] (500)
               )
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @cassette_1 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_2 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_3 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_4 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @total NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

WHILE CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @cassette_1 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
  SELECT @cassette_2 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
  SELECT @cassette_3 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
  SELECT @cassette_4 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_1)
SELECT @cassette_1
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_2)
SELECT @cassette_2
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_3)
SELECT @cassette_2
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_4)
SELECT @cassette_4
INSERT INTO @returnList (total)
SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

This is my code to call the object:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('005031812180200000100aRemaining Inside Terminala Cassette 1(BIN1)/c:HTG 21,000a Cassette 2(BIN2)/c:HTG 23,000a Cassette 3(BIN3)/d:HTG 47,000a Cassette 4(BIN4)/d:HTG 48,000a Total : HTG 139,000aaaad')
```

The string will be calling a string inside a table.

This is the result in getting right now:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60eb5/2

I need everything in one registry (I know is the insert thats making a new one) but I don't seem to get it done, also I'm only getting the final part in every column (cassette 4)

Comment: The letter 'a' is the delimiter? That is..... not a good idea. Even if it is 'a ' and you look for the space after it, what happens when a word in your string legitimately ends with an 'a' and you split the string based on that?

Comment: i know its probably not the best idea, but i get that data from another process and thats the only pattern that the data has.

i forgot to specify that i cant do it counting the characters, because the number following HTG can go anywhere between X and X,XXX,XXX character

also that string is always going to have that same format, with the same word, so there's never going to be a word ending in "a "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop you're setting all `@casette_n` variables in each iteration. Either unroll the loop to four groups of the statements or take the right variable according to a counter and assign the value to it. I opted for the first possibility in the following code.

The `INSERT` in the end can be written with one `SELECT`. So only one row is inserted.

And there seems to be some header with a name or something in the beginning. You have to address that too. I added it too the output, but if you don't want that, you can discard it. But it must be removed from the string prior searching for the 1st cassette.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([name] [nvarchar] (500),
                    [cassette_1] [nvarchar] (500),
                    [cassette_2] [nvarchar] (500),
                    [cassette_3] [nvarchar] (500),
                    [cassette_4] [nvarchar] (500),
                    [total] [nvarchar] (500)
                   )
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_1 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_2 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_3 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cassette_4 NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @total NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 -- getting the name
 SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)
 SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
 SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

 -- getting 1st cassette
 SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)
 SELECT @cassette_1 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
 SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

 -- getting 2nd cassette
 SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)
 SELECT @cassette_2 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
 SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

 -- getting 3rd cassette
 SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)
 SELECT @cassette_3 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
 SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

 -- getting 4th cassette
 SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('a ', @stringToSplit)
 SELECT @cassette_4 = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
 SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)

 -- inserting one row
 INSERT INTO @returnList (name, cassette_1, cassette_2, cassette_3, cassette_4, total)
 SELECT @name, @cassette_1, @cassette_2, @cassette_3, @cassette_4, @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

But that will only work if there are exactly four cassettes! You might want to rethink that for an arbitrary number of cassettes if such a string must be processed too.

And of course you're screwed if an `'a '` appears somewhere in the data, like in that name header, say `'It's a wonderful day'`.

Comment: That's just perfect, thanks.... it's exactly what i need to do.

as for the numbers of cassettes it will always by 4, its a hardware limit

Comment: how can i do if im pulling this string from a table that has other records? let me explain the table structure is [terminal] [date_time] [activity] in activity theres a lot of data i dont need, i only need to pull those registries with the words 'Remaining Inside Terminal' as it is in the header you are mentioning, and repeat this code so i can get a table with all the registries that include the remaining data like its presented in here

Answer (score 0):

your function is almost there...
but instead of

```
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_1)
SELECT @cassette_1
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_2)
SELECT @cassette_2
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_3)
SELECT @cassette_2
INSERT INTO @returnList (cassette_4)
SELECT @cassette_4
INSERT INTO @returnList (total)
SELECT @stringToSplit
```

u can use this

```
INSERT INTO @returnList 
SELECT @cassette_1,@cassette_2,@cassette_3,@cassette_4,@stringToSplit
```

CMIIW,
Please let me know if this help...

Thanks

Comment: thanks, that actualy solve one of the issues, but its still showing only CASSETTE_4 and TOTAL data correctly

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fef9/1